# How to limit page access only to localhost?

Tags: asp.net, security, localhost

Is there a way in asp.net to limit the access to a web page only from localhost?

Comment: What do you want to happen if a non-localhost request is made?

Comment: Yes, I think we understand access is restricted... but exactly **what** should happen? **What** should the user see? Sould they be directed somewhere?  (If you're replying to an individual, you need to put a `@` followed by their username, otherwise they will not receive a notification)

Comment: @freefaller sure (about @), well one shoulnd't even try to access this page, so it can be some 4xx http response. I'm thinking of looking at the HttpRequest.IsLocal property for that matter.

Comment: Yes, `HttpRequest.IsLocal` would work for you. But you will want to redirect to a 404 based page (returning a 404 could start effecting the ability for the page to be viewed - although I'm not 100% sure on this one)

Answer (score 13):

```
     if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
     { 
       Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
       Response.End();
     }
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this for a "web page" then I'd use IsLocal, but if you want a subdirectory solution I'd use Url Rewrite 2. http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=urlrewrite2. If you don't have this installed already, go and get it as it's very useful. I believe it will be standard on IIS8.

Then add this to your web.config under `<system.webServer/>`

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>
    <!-- if this rule matches stopProcessing any further rules -->
    <rule name="Block Remote Access to Admin" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" enabled="true">
      <!-- specify secure folder matching trailing / or $ == end of string-->
      <match url="projects(/|$)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <!-- Allow local host -->
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="localhost" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="::1" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <!-- by default, deny all requests. Options here are "AbortRequest" (drop connection), "Redirect" to a 403 page, "CustomResponse", etc.  -->
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusDescription="Forbidden" statusReason="Access to this URL is restricted"/>
      <!-- or send the caller to an error page, home page etc
           <action type="Redirect" url="/public/forbidden.htm" redirectType="Temporary" />
      -->
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be a solution:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string localhost = Request.Url.Authority;
    if (localhost.IndexOf("localhost") != 0)
        Response.Redirect("defalut.aspx");
}
```