# ASP.NET Method local access only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller who gets a request.

I want to restrict it, so it is only locally.

I can't just restrict the web application to local access only, because it is only one particular method, that needs to be restricted.

How do i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself, and other people is how do you define a connection is local?

Comment: What sort of controller are you wanting to use, a MVC or WebApi controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to limit page access only to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879500/how-to-limit-page-access-only-to-localhost)
one of the answers:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
{ 
    Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
    Response.End();
}
```

you might want to use [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The question is tagged WebApi, this answer will only work on a MVC controller.  WebApi controllers probably shouldn't access HttpContext.

Comment: didn't even notice it =)

Answer (score 0):

Check UserHostAddress

```
if(Request.UserHostAddress != "127.0.0.1" && Request.UserHostAddress != "::1")
{
    throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden.");
}
```